# How can I divide a matrix into several parts using the \ eqarray command?

Tags: microsoft-word, equations, equation-editor

Good morning, I am trying to incorporate the following expression using the equation tools in Word.

[image]

Thanks to the valuable answer I received in this space I was able to use the command \ eqarray and raise it using the Word equation tools following the code

\eqarray(Δu_t=&I_t "(" -0.070&+&0.381Δu_(t-1)&+&0.345Δu_(t-2)&+&0.126Δu_(t-3)&+&0.084Δu_(t-4)&-&0.148Δu_(t-12) ")" &+(1-I_t )&"(" -0.004&-&0.039Δu_(t-1)&+&0.122Δu_(t-2)&+&0.179Δu_(t-3)&+&0.159Δu_(t-4)&-&0.126Δu_(t-12) ")" @&(-3.28)&&(3.84)&&(5.22)&&(1.90)&&(1.25)&&(-2.08)&&(-0.47)&&(-0.57)&&(2.48)&&(3.73)&&(3.35)&&(-3.09))here

Whose result, in the form of an equation is

[image]

The problem is that, since it is a matrix of equations, the expression is long and is outside the margins of the document. I wanted to know if there is any way to divide it into several parts, adjust it into more lines or express it in such a way that it remains as it is recorded in the text from which the image was obtained. I appreciate the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to me to be four possible general approaches to this.

1. Try to persuade the Word equation to wrap.
2. Insert a sequence of `\eqarray(top term@bottom term)` terms and try to use Equation Manual Breaks to split the terms manually into 3 rows. For the first term, use `\eqarray(topterm@)` (i.e. no bottom term)
3. Use nested \eqarray terms like this:

   ```
   \eqarray(line1@line2@line3)
   ```

where line2 consists of a sequence of `\eqarray(top term@bottom term)` terms.

1. Use something more like this

   ```
   \eqarray(row1@row2@row3@row4@row5@row6)
   ```
2. Split the equation into several separate Word Equations

I didn't get far with (1) although I can just about imagine that using a hanging indent and paragraph indents you might be able to do it

Equation Editor seems to be very particular about where you use Equation Manual Breaks (frankly, I'm not surprised) so I didn't find a way to do (2). In any case, I'm not convinced it would be easy to get the "hanging indent" correct.

Although (4) might actually be the easiest way to get the final output and adjust the line spacing, the problem is that it separates the `top term` and `bottom term` values from each other so that it's much more difficult to see what you're doing. Option (3) keeps each pair of terms close together.

So here is the best I've managed to do :

```
\eqarray(\eqarray(Δu_t =@)&\eqarray(&I_t "(" -0.070@(-3.28))  \eqarray(+ &0.381Δu_(t-1) @&(3.84))  \eqarray(+ &0.345Δu_(t-2) @&(5.22))  \eqarray(+ &0.126Δu_(t-3) @&1.90))  \eqarray(+ &0.084Δu_(t-4) @&(1.25))@&\eqarray(@- &0.148Δu_(t-12) ")" @&(2.08)) \eqarray(@+ (1-I_t )&"(" -0.004@&(-0.47))  \eqarray(@- &0.039Δ_(t-1) @&(-0.57))  \eqarray(@+ &0.122Δu_(t-2) @&(2.48))@&\eqarray(@+ &0.179Δu_(t-3) @&(3.73))  \eqarray(@+ &0.159Δu_(t-4) @&(3.35))  \eqarray(@- &0.126Δu_(t-12) ")" @&(-3.09) ))
```

it's probably helpful to split that up a bit:

The start of the outer array:

```
\eqarray(
```

The hanging indent part:

```
\eqarray(Δu_t =@)
```

Remainder of line one:

```
&\eqarray(&I_t "(" -0.070@(-3.28)) 
\eqarray(+ &0.381Δu_(t-1) @&(3.84)) 
\eqarray(+ &0.345Δu_(t-2) @&(5.22)) 
\eqarray(+ &0.126Δu_(t-3) @&1.90))
\eqarray(+ &0.084Δu_(t-4) @&(1.25))
```

Line 2:

```
@&\eqarray(@- &0.148Δu_(t-12) ")" @&(2.08)) 
\eqarray(@+ (1-I_t )&"(" -0.004@&(-0.47))  
\eqarray(@- &0.039Δ_(t-1) @&(-0.57))  
\eqarray(@+ &0.122Δu_(t-2) @&(2.48))
```

Line 3:

```
@&\eqarray(@+ &0.179Δu_(t-3) @&(3.73))  
\eqarray(@+ &0.159Δu_(t-4) @&(3.35))  
\eqarray(@- &0.126Δu_(t-12) ")" @&(-3.09) )
```

End of the outer array:

```
)
```

Notes:

There are *two* spaces before most of the `\eqarray` terms. One causes build-up, and the other is necessary for spacing.

Most of the "+" and "-" signs need a space after them to prevent build-up from treating them as unary operators when "binary operator" spacing is whay is needed.

In the second and third rows of the three rows of terms I have added an "@" immediately after each \eqarray( in order to create more space between the three rows. You can omit them depending on what spacing you actually want. There are some vertical spacing features in the right-click menu of the Equation editor, but I was only able to use them with a much simpler non-array equation. Alternatively, you coud consider using a phantom, e.g. change the Line 2 code as follows:

```
@\vphantom(X/X/X/X ) &\eqarray(- &0.148Δu_(t-12) ")" @&(2.08)) 
\eqarray(+ (1-I_t )&"(" -0.004@&(-0.47))  
\eqarray(- &0.039Δ_(t-1) @&(-0.57))  
\eqarray(+ &0.122Δu_(t-2) @&(2.48))
```

i.e. insert `\vphantom(X/X/X/X)` and change `\eqarray(@` to `\eqarray(` .

Then make the equivalent changes in the Line 3 code. The phantoms are visible or invisible depending on whether or not hidden text is shown, so you can use *show* the phantom to see how it is affecting spacing and hide it when you have finished.

For anyone else looking at this, you can get the Δ using `\Delta`

Comment: Dear, first I wanted to thank you for your collaboration in solving my problem. It is very well explained step by step. Regarding the solution you are proposing, I have had problems when executing the second line as you have it, I do not know where the problem may be or it is an error that I am making.Regarding the \ phantom function I have used its \ hphantom derivative and it seems that I have found a solution to what I am looking for.

Comment: your explanation has been of great help to me, the option you propose with \ phantom helped me to propose the solution through multiple equations, again thank you very much for your time, effort and dedication!

Answer (score 0):

What I have achieved is to run the first line of the mathematical expression as presented in the image using the function \eqarray

\eqarray(Δu_t=&I_t "(" -0.070&+&0.381Δu_(t-1)&+&0.345Δu_(t-2)&+&0.126Δu_(t-3)&+&0.084Δu_(t-4)@&(-3.28)&&(3.84)&&(5.22)&&(1.90)&&(1.25))[shift+ENTER]

Right away I used the multiple equation option, which is accomplished before exiting the equation by using the [shift + ENTER] key combination instead of ENTER to add a new equation. In the second space that has been created for me I have added the following command

\eqarray(\hphantom(Δu_t=)&-0.148Δu_(t-12) ")" &+(1-I_t )&"(" -0.004&-&0.039Δu_(t-1)&+&0.122Δu_(t-12)@&(-2.08)&&(-0.47)&&(-0.57)&&(2.48) ) [shift-ENTER]

and in the same way as it was done in line 2, using the multiple equations option I have once again used [shift + ENTER] to add the third line that is given as follows:

\eqarray(\hphantom(Δu_t=)&+0.179Δu_(t-3)&+&0.159Δu_(t-4)&-&0.126Δu_(t-12) ")" @&(3.73)&&(3.35)&&(-3.09) )

The final result of the equation in its linear form is as follows

[image]

where Δ = \ Delta

And in its professional form it is as indicated

[image]

If anyone finds a better way please don't hesitate to share it, your effort and contribution is appreciated!